# Mopidy/Mopify: Search box autocompletes artists, but doesn't find songs

Tags: raspbian

I'm using Raspbian Wheezy and have mopidy installed. I tried using the mopify web extension to access Spotify. Even though I am perfectly able to access the web interface, I can't find any songs. I can enter artists and songs in the search box, auto completion and suggestions work as well, but when I select, for example, an artist from the list of suggestions, it just doesn't load any songs.

Is this connected to the fact that other third party spotify players only work with a spotify premium account? Mopify does not ask for any login details, so it might be outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (Mopify's developer) stumbled upon this topic by accident, but to answer your question:

Mopify doesn't require a spotify premium account, but Mopidy does. You reason you see results in the auto complete box is because Mopify uses the Spotify API for generating those results. After you've clicked on an item it uses Mopidy to fetch the detailed results. At this point Mopidy needs your Spotify (premium) account.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Is there any hope Mopidy will work with the free version of Spotify in the future?

Comment: I don't think so. Mopidy can only rely on the Spotify API, which only allows (for as far as I know) Spotify Premium users to stream music.

If have more questions about [Mopidy-Mopify](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/mopidy-mopify) or [Mopidy-Spotify](https://github.com/mopidy/mopidy-spotify) I would suggest you to use the issue tracker on their repository pages.